Так(,) я же и заказал ваш телефон!
Нужна запятушонка?
— Кто вы?
— Так(,) я же и заказал ваш телефон!

Не нужна , ТАК — частица. По словарю: 3. Употр. для подчёркивания, выделения при противопоставлении, сопоставлении (кто вы — так я же...).
